# Why are my network connections great on Ubuntu but awful on Windows 7/8.1?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, home-networking, windows-8.1

Several months ago, my girlfriend started having connectivity problems on her Windows 7 Dell laptop. Her connection to the network would drop entirely every ten/fifteen minutes or so, and she'd have to reset the router. Her access speeds during most of the uptime were abysmal. After performing a fresh install of Windows 7 on her computer- no help at all- I tried running Ubuntu from a flash drive and poof! Beautiful speeds, flawless execution. I installed Ubuntu as a dual boot on her computer, and she's had absolutely no connectivity problems since.

Just last week, two other computers on the same network started having similar issues: one an HP running Windows 7, the other a Lenovo X230T running Windows 8.1. I performed pings from command prompts on both. All of the packets were received, but the delays were on the order of 1520 ms for google.com.

So I tried running Ubuntu on my Lenovo from a flash drive and, again, poof! Ping speeds dropped to 150 ms maximum. I'm posting this question from Ubuntu.

I've confirmed that it isn't a router issue. The same speeds present themselves when I'm plugged in via ethernet (slightly faster, but still with a huge delay before websites are loaded.) Bypassing the DNS by visiting 4.4.4.4 (for example) doesn't help. Neither do drivers seem to be at fault, as all of them are up-to-date. Full system scans from Avast! (the Lenovo) and Kaspersky (the HP) report 0 infections. I can't for the life of me figure out what might be causing the issue, especially considering that it occurs consistently across three very different computers, two of which are running very different OSs.

Just wondering if anyone here might have some insight. Apologies if I've left out several pieces of crucial information- I'm just getting started with networks, and have very little idea what I'm doing. While I'll contact Time Warner (the ISP) about this whenever I have time next week, I'd still like to learn what's at the root of the problem.